# What should I do with unrelated answer due to the fact that my question wasn't clear at the time?

Tags: support

After posting this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631477/how-to-avoid-re-testing-the-same-behavior-while-following-tdd-rules-in-javascrip), someone tried to answer it.

However, he missed the question itself. This indicated me that my question could be misleading because it wasn't enough straightforward.

Therefore, I refined my question by removing unnecessary stuff and clarified the point.

But now the unrelated answer remain, should something be done about it?

Comment: Downvote an unhelpful answer.  Usually the poster will delete it.

Comment: You comment letting the answerer know they missed the point of the question and ask them to look at your edited version. If they don't return after a while and fix/delete the answer, feel free to downvote the answer. Whatever you do, _do not_ flag it. Moderators cannot (and will not) do anything about an incorrect answer. If it looks like an answer, they will leave it be.

Comment: I would comment **thanking the user for trying to help**, but *politely* point out the fault in your question (that you've corrected) and how their answer doesn't address it. I wouldn't down-vote it straight away as user may take it badly / personally.

Comment: @TZHX You should *absolutely* be downvoting incorrect answers or answers that don't actually answer the question being asked.  The purpose of downvotes is to call out unhelpful posts, to which this one unquestionably is.  The fact that they were trying to help is irrelevant to how you should vote.  You vote on the quality of the post, not the intentions of the author.

Comment: @Kendra: You can always remove your downvote when the post no longer deserves it. You can even decide to upvote, if that's merited.

Comment: @Deduplicator I realized I should've mentioned that a moment ago, but my connection hiccuped about then. Thank you. :) Axmim, as Deduplicator has mentioned, you can remove a downvote after an edit, or even reverse it to an upvote. If the answerer deletes their answer, then they will regain the rep from the downvote. So don't be afraid to downvote their answer for being incorrect- But I would highly advise that comment- Let them know what's wrong with the answer so they can fix it more easily.

Comment: @Servy I didn't suggest not down voting at all -- just don't start the dialogue with a -1. People have been known to take voting personally and so in a case where the question has changed I think a grace period would contribute to avoiding unnecessary drama.

Comment: Your original question does state that you're trying to avoid using a private method. Your edits make your question clearer but it isn't as though you edited it into a different question or left out critical information. I don't think this was your fault.

Comment: @TZHX If someone is going to take a downvote personally when they post an incorrect answer why would it be any better to get the downvote a bit later than to get one right away?  And people tend to not take downvotes personally, they tend to take getting called out for posting a bad answer personally.  Whether it's done through a vote or a comment tends to make little difference.

Comment: @Servy ok. As you will. I've not looked at the posts in question so from this question assumed the unsuitability of answer was due to lack of clarity in op question. If it is just a bad answer that's different.

Comment: @TZHX The answer doesn't answer the question.  Whether it's because the author misunderstood what the question was asking or not isn't really relevant.  At the end of the day, it doesn't answer the question.  This is of course why we also close unclear questions instead of trying to guess at what the author is asking and answering anyway; it results in people posting bad answers that don't successfully answer the question.