# Re-ask or reopen a question in case it's closed before edits were made

Tags: discussion

I am trying to summarize what happened with [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46246954/updating-a-maps-value-before-collect).

Note: I read existing questions like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346440/my-question-is-being-close-voted-as-opinion-based-i-edit-it-before-the-5th-vote), but the course of action isn't clear to me.

1. The question was asked.
2. The question received a downvote. There were comments that the question was 'suitable for debugging'.
3. I asked if providing the input and output of the code would help which received affirmation.
4. By the time I could add the entire code, input and output, there were three closing votes.

Now if the question is closed, how shall I proceed?

Comment: `closed !== deleted`. The whole purpose of closing is to give the OP time to edit it so that it can be reopened, and if that edit doesn't occur, it can remain closed and eventually be deleted.

Comment: Oh ! But then who reopens it ? I guess the 'attention' it would receive will be hampered or am I missing something ?

Comment: The first edit  you make after it is closed pushes the question into the reopen queue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: Not to mention that all that information is linked in the close banner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your edit was enough to fix the problems with the question, then the final close votes will (ideally) never come, and you won't have to worry about them. The existing close votes will eventually age away, but even as long as they sit there, they aren't hurting anything. The question is *not* closed, and can still be answered.

If your edit comes too late, or isn't enough to persuade subsequent reviewers, then the question might indeed end up closed. In that case, you'd do what everyone does when their question gets closed: edit it to address the concerns brought up in the comments and enumerated in the chosen close reason. That edit will push the question into a special review queue, where community members review questions that have been edited after being closed to see if they are suitable for re-opening. Again, if your edit was sufficient to address the problems with the question, then the question will be re-opened.

If your edits *still* weren't sufficient to persuade the reviewers, then you'll need to work harder. It's time to get *real* serious about reading the comments that people have left and make sure that you're addressing their concerns. Reach out to them and ask for additional clarification if you still don't know what is needed. Read carefully through our Help Center, paying special attention to [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (assuming the latter applies to your particular question).

If you've read all of that, consulted all the resources you can, addressed *all* the problems brought up in comments, and even reached out to those commenters, but *still* haven't managed to be successful in improving your question to the point where it can be re-opened, then you can escalate the issue to Meta. Ask a question tagged [support](/questions/tagged/support), [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question), and [reopen-closed](/questions/tagged/reopen-closed), link to your question, and ask what else you need to do to address the problems and get it re-opened. Avoid ranting about how the close voters are "Nazis" and how Stack Overflow is "unfair" and "filled with trolls"; focus on the technical issues of how to improve your question and convincing community members to reopen it. A key point is remembering that it doesn't have to be the same people who voted to close your question that vote to reopen it. You don't have to convince the original audience; you just have to convince five new people. There are many more than five regular participants on Meta; try not to offend them in how you phrase the support request.

(Note that this is intentionally a very general answer; none of it is meant to apply specifically to your question, your circumstances, or imply in any way that *this* question is phrased unconstructively.)